# basic how-to-use of SSH

Tags: networking, ssh

This is pretty embarrassing, but I'm completely new to and know nothing about SSH other than that it's used to connect to a server remotely.

I'm given the following information:

```
HostName somename(from local network) or some.ip.add.ress(for connecting from outside network)
Port 12345
User someusername
identityfile ~/.ssh/someidfile

in case of ssh-ing to server other than somename (above),
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p name@address
```

So let's say I want to ssh to that server remotely.

Do I need them to make me an account to be able to do so?

Also, supposing that I ssh from the outside network, what would be the exact syntax?

Finally, if someone has installed some application on the server, say xcode, do you get to share the application installed once you ssh to the same server?

I know these sound like dumb questions to most of you, but please help me out.

(I'm working on Maverick btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -i /path/to/identityfile -p 12345 someusername@some.ip.add.ress
```

should work

It seems that you already have account.

No. You cannot share application via SSH

Comment: I've tried it, but it says connect to host somehostname port 22: Connection refused, even though I typed -p 12345... why could this be?